# XMPP MUC - Automatically join to room after added membership by another user

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd, multiuserchat

When I open my application, user gets MUC JIDs to be joined and then user can see if there are any new messagesm, he can open room etc. Is it possible to add new MUC in realtime to the availabe rooms when other user will give the membership?

Scenario:

- user1 logs in, rooms are displayed.
- user2 grants membershipt to user1 to room1 that user1 was not there
- user1's list is refreshed with the new room - room1

Thanks, Michal

Comment: "When I open my application"... probably it all depends on your application, right?

Comment: @Badlop but the question is rather if I can listen somehow if the user was added. The similar way I can listen if there is new message in the chat room

Comment: When an occupant is granted membership, this change is broadcasted to the other room occupants, see https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#example-123